# Syntax Errors in VHDL with Case statement and Process Declarations

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl, cpu-architecture

I'm attempting to model a control unit with a reduced instruction set in VHDL. I've been compiling a lot to ensure that the code still compile, but somewhere along the line, I must have done something wrong. After fleshing out the decode states for many of the instructions, I started getting the following set of errors.

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at controlunit.vhd(164) near text "when";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("when" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at controlunit.vhd(176) near text "when";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("when" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at controlunit.vhd(183) near text "when";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("when" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at controlunit.vhd(190) near text "case";  expecting "if"
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at controlunit.vhd(195) near text "Begin";  expecting ":=", or "<="
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at controlunit.vhd(203) near text "process";  expecting "if"
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at controlunit.vhd(204) near text "behavior";  expecting "if"

Normally, these kinds of errors would be well within my ability to fix, but I've gone through my code multiple time, and as far as I can tell, all of the process blocks and case statements are defined correctly.

I'm afraid that, since I'm rather new to VHDL, I might be missing some syntactic subtlety that I'd never spot on my own. Can any VHDL expert help me isolate the issue in my code? Thank you!

You can find my code in the code block below.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

entity ControlUnit is
 port(
    clk: IN  std_logic; 
    Mem_rd: OUT  std_logic  :='1';      --signal to read from RAM/ROM
    Mem_wr: OUT  std_logic  :='1';      --signal to write RAM
    Mem_cs: OUT std_logic :='1';        --signal to select either RAM or ROM 
    Z: IN std_logic;                    --zero signal from ALU
    N: IN std_logic;                    --negative signal from ALU
    R_we: OUT std_logic;                --read/write enable signal to register file
    ld_op: OUT std_logic;               --bus control signal for memory load operations
    st_op: OUT std_logic;               --bus control signal for memory read operations
    ctl_wd: OUT std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);          --processor control word
    const_out: OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);      --constant value from instruction
    CU_addr_bus: INOUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  --processor address bus connection
    CU_data_bus: INOUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  --processor data bus connection
    run: IN std_logic;                  --signal allowing processor to execute its program
    rst: IN  std_logic                  --system reset signal
     );
end ControlUnit;


architecture Behavior of ControlUnit is
-- Control Unit states for multi-cycle instruction execution
type states is (Reset, Fetch, Decode, Execute, WB);
signal CurrState, NextState : states;

-- Instruction set types
type ops is (nop, subx, orx, jmp, addx, andx, notx, srlx, sllx, ld, st, hlt, ret, addi, ba, bn, bz, sethi, call);
signal CurrOp, NextOp : ops;

-- Internal signal declarations
signal CurrPC, CurrSP, CurrIR, CurrDisp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal NextPC, NextSP, NextIR, NextDisp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal PCaEN, SPEN, PCdEN : std_logic;
signal currStatus, nextStatus : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); --N & Z

begin
-- tri-state enables:
addr_bus <= CurrPC when PCaEN='1' else     
                CurrSP when SPEN='1' else 
                (others=>'Z');
data_bus <= CurrPC when PCdEN='1' else       
                (others => 'Z');
    
CombLogic : process(CurrState, run, CurrPC, CurrSP, CurrIR, CurrOp, data_bus)
    begin
    case CurrState is
        when Reset =>           -------------------------RESET-------------------------
            NextPC <= x"0080"; NextSP <= x"04FE"; 
            NextIR <= x"0000"; NextOp <= nop;
            NextStatus <= "00"; NextDisp <= x"0000";
            PCaEN <= '1'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';      -- setup     fetch
            mem_cs <= '0'; mem_rd <= '0'; mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low; setup fetch
            if run = '0' then NextState <= Reset;         -- active low run
            else NextState <= Fetch; 
            end if;
            
        when Fetch =>   -------------------------FETCH-------------------------
            NextPC <= currPC; NextSP <= currSP; 
            NextIR <= data_bus; NextOp <= currOP;
            PCaEN <= '1'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';      
            mem_cs <= '0'; mem_rd <= '0'; mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low
            R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= (others => '0'); const_out <= x"FFFF";
            NextState <= Decode;
        
        when Decode =>  ------------------------DECODE-------------------------
            --fill in decode logic
            if currIR(15) = '1' then NextOp <= call;
                NextPC <= CurrPC+1; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';   -- store CurrPC to M[SP]
                mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= "0000"; const_out <= x"0000";
            else if currIR(14) = '1' then
                case currOP(10 downto 8) is
                    when "000" => NextOP <= hlt;   --set signals for hlt
                    when "001" => NextOP <= ret;   --set signals for ret
                    when "011" => NextOP <= addi;  --set signals for addi
                    when "100" => NextOP <= ba;    --set signals for ba
                    when "101" => NextOP <= bn;    --set signals for bn
                    when "110" => NextOP <= bz;    --set signals for bz
                    when "111" => NextOP <= sethi; --set signals for sethi
                end case;
            else
                case currOP(10 downto 7) is
                    when "1010" => NextOP <= nop; --set signals for nop
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= x"0000"; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "1001" => NextOP <= subx; --set signals for subx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "1000" => NextOP <= orx; --set signals for orx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0111" => NextOP <= jmp; --set signals for jmp
                        NextPC <= CurrPCL; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0110" => NextOP <= addx; --set signals for addx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0101" => NextOP <= andx; --set signals for andx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0100" => NextOP <= notx; --set signals for notx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0011" => NextOP <= srlx; --set signals for srlx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0010" => NextOP <= sllx; --set signals for sllx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0001" => NextOP <= ld;   --set signals for ld
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '0'; mem_rd <= '0'; mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0000" => NextOP <= st;   --set signals for st
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '0'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '0';
                        R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= currOP(14 downto 0)&'0'; const_out <= x"0000";
                end case;
            end if;
            NextState <= Execute;
        
        
        when Execute => -------------------------EXECUTE-------------------------
            case CurrOp is
                when call => --call
                    NextPC <= CurrPC+1; NextSP <= CurrSP; NextIR <= CurrIR; nextStatus <= currStatus; nextDisp <= currDisp;
                    PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '1'; PCdEN <= '1';   -- store CurrPC to M[SP]
                    mem_cs <= '0'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '0';
                    R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= "0000"; const_out <= x"0000";
            --for bn and bz, execution of operation is dependent on signals N and Z
                when others => null;
            end case;
            NextState <= WB;
        
        when WB =>      -------------------------WB-------------------------
            NextPC <= '0'&currIR(6 downto 0); NextSP <= CurrSP - 1; NextIR <= CurrIR; NextOp <= CurrOp;
            PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';      -- setup fetch
            mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low; setup fetch
            R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= "0000"; const_out <= x"0000";
            NextState <= Fetch;
        
        when others =>  -------------------------OTHERS-------------------------
            -- Should never be in this state!
            NextPC <= x"00"; NextSP <= x"00"; NextIR <= x"00"; NextOp <= call;
            PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';      
            mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low
            R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= "00"; const_out <= x"FF";    
            NextState <= Reset;
    end case;
end process;

-- Sequential Logic (asynchronous reset; registers update at positive-edge clock)  
Regs : process(clk,rst)
Begin
    if rst = '0' then CurrState <= Reset;  -- Active Low Reset
        CurrOp <= sethi; CurrPC <= x"80"; CurrSP <= x"FF"; CurrIR <= (others=>'0');
        CurrStatus <= "00";
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then CurrState <= NextState; 
        CurrOp <= NextOp; CurrPC <= NextPC; CurrSP <= NextSP; CurrIR <= NextIR; 
        CurrStatus <= NextStatus;
    end if;
end process Regs;
end behavior;
```

Comment: General comments: 1) don't write inlined code like this, because it is very hard to maintain. It is for instance not easy to comment out one statement this way. 2) Don't use CamelCase in VHDL. VHDL is not case sensitive. So everything gets converted to lower case in simulation, which makes it difficult to find variables. Use underscores instead. 3) improve the naming of you variables for readilibilty: SPEN --> SP_enable (or even more info). Finally 4) comment your code. And "NextOP <= hlt;   --set signals for hlt" is not a proper comment: really explain what is happening.

Comment: The OPs account has been inactive for 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Instruction set types
type ops is (nop, subx, orx, jmp, addx, andx, notx, srlx, sllx, ld, st, hlt, ret, addi, ba, bn, bz, sethi, call);
signal CurrOp, NextOp : ops;
```

For example `CurrOp` is an enumerated type with values shown as ops enumerations.  Yet you have slices of `CurrOp`:

```
case currOP(10 downto 8) is

case currOP(10 downto 7) is
```

And your `when` expressions for the case statements are string literals respectively with a length of 3 or 4.

So CurrOp isn't an array type you can't slice it and compare it to strings.

Now why analysis get's this far is without telling you this is entertaining. The expression is being evaluated at elaboration time and not analysis time unlike say the target of a signal assignment:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    -- Instruction set types
    type ops is (nop, subx, orx, jmp, addx, andx, notx, srlx, sllx, ld, st, hlt, ret, addi, ba, bn, bz, sethi, call);
    signal CurrOp, NextOp: ops;

begin
    CurrOp(10 downto 7) <= "1001";
    NextOp(10 downto 8) <= "011";

end architecture;
```

> ghdl -a foo.vhdl 
>   foo.vhdl:13:11: type of prefix is not an array
>   foo.vhdl:14:11: type of prefix is not an array
>   ghdl: compilation error

(-a is the ghdl analysis command)

Effectively a choice can only be an ops enumeration value.  To make it more palatable you're allowed choices:

> choices ::=  choice { | choice }

You can also assign the default for all the signals you are guaranteed to assign in a choice right before a case statement then assign only those with different values in each case statement alternative.  In the same simulation delta only the last assignment will be scheduled (there's only one future event).

Along with a plethora of errors, the major thing stopping the further analysis was an `else if` where and `else was appropriate.

A found lots or errors while trouble shooting, you'd want to compare these for the same syntactical position in your file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
-- use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ControlUnit is
 port(
    clk: IN  std_logic; 
    Mem_rd: OUT  std_logic  :='1';      --signal to read from RAM/ROM
    Mem_wr: OUT  std_logic  :='1';      --signal to write RAM
    Mem_cs: OUT std_logic :='1';        --signal to select either RAM or ROM 
    Z: IN std_logic;                    --zero signal from ALU
    N: IN std_logic;                    --negative signal from ALU
    R_we: OUT std_logic;                --read/write enable signal to register file
    ld_op: OUT std_logic;               --bus control signal for memory load operations
    st_op: OUT std_logic;               --bus control signal for memory read operations
    ctl_wd: OUT std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);          --processor control word
    const_out: OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);      --constant value from instruction
    CU_addr_bus: INOUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  --processor address bus connection
    CU_data_bus: INOUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  --processor data bus connection
    run: IN std_logic;                  --signal allowing processor to execute its program
    rst: IN  std_logic                  --system reset signal
     );
end ControlUnit;


architecture Behavior of ControlUnit is
    -- Control Unit states for multi-cycle instruction execution
    type states is (Reset, Fetch, Decode, Execute, WB);
    signal CurrState, NextState : states;

    -- Instruction set types
    type ops is (nop, subx, orx, jmp, addx, andx, notx, srlx, sllx, ld, st, hlt, ret, addi, ba, bn, bz, sethi, call);
    signal CurrOp, NextOp : ops;

    -- Internal signal declarations
    signal CurrPC, CurrSP, CurrIR, CurrDisp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal NextPC, NextSP, NextIR, NextDisp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal PCaEN, SPEN, PCdEN : std_logic;
    signal currStatus, nextStatus : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); --N & Z

begin
-- tri-state enables:
CU_addr_bus <= CurrPC when PCaEN='1' else     
                CurrSP when SPEN='1' else 
                (others=>'Z');
CU_data_bus <= CurrPC when PCdEN='1' else       
                (others => 'Z');

CombLogic : process(CurrState, run, CurrPC, CurrSP, CurrIR, CurrOp, CU_data_bus)
    begin
    case CurrState is
        when Reset =>           -------------------------RESET-------------------------
            NextPC <= x"0080"; 
            NextSP <= x"04FE"; 
            NextIR <= x"0000"; 
            NextOp <= nop;
            NextStatus <= "00"; 
            NextDisp <= x"0000";
            PCaEN <= '1'; 
            SPEN <= '0'; 
            PCdEN <= '0';      -- setup     fetch
            mem_cs <= '0'; 
            mem_rd <= '0';
            mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low; setup fetch
            if run = '0' then NextState <= Reset;         -- active low run
                else NextState <= Fetch; 
            end if;

        when Fetch =>   -------------------------FETCH-------------------------
            NextPC <= currPC; 
            NextSP <= currSP; 
            NextIR <= CU_data_bus; 
            NextOp <= currOP;
            PCaEN <= '1'; 
            SPEN <= '0'; 
            PCdEN <= '0';      
            mem_cs <= '0'; 
            mem_rd <= '0'; 
            mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low
            R_we <= '0'; 
            ctl_wd <= (others => '0'); 
            const_out <= x"FFFF";
            NextState <= Decode;

        when Decode =>  ------------------------DECODE-------------------------
            --fill in decode logic
            if currIR(15) = '1' then 
                NextOp <= call;
                NextPC <= std_logic_vector (unsigned(CurrPC) + 1); 
                NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                nextDisp <= currDisp;
                PCaEN <= '0'; 
                SPEN <= '0'; 
                PCdEN <= '0';   -- store CurrPC to M[SP]
                mem_cs <= '1'; 
                mem_rd <= '1'; 
                mem_wr <= '1';
                R_we <= '0'; 
                ctl_wd <= (others => '0'); 
                const_out <= x"0000";
            elsif currIR(14) = '1' then
                case currIR(10 downto 8) is
                    when "000" => NextOP <= hlt;   --set signals for hlt
                    when "001" => NextOP <= ret;   --set signals for ret
                    when "011" => NextOP <= addi;  --set signals for addi
                    when "100" => NextOP <= ba;    --set signals for ba
                    when "101" => NextOP <= bn;    --set signals for bn
                    when "110" => NextOP <= bz;    --set signals for bz
                    when "111" => NextOP <= sethi; --set signals for sethi
                    when others => NextOp <= nop;
                end case;
            else
                case currIR(10 downto 7) is
                    when "1010" => 
                        NextOP <= nop; --set signals for nop
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1';
                         mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '0'; 
                        ctl_wd <= (others => '0'); 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "1001" => 
                        NextOP <= subx; --set signals for subx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC;
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "1000" => 
                        NextOP <= orx; --set signals for orx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0111" => 
                        NextOP <= jmp; --set signals for jmp
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '0'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0110" => 
                        NextOP <= addx; --set signals for addx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0101" => 
                        NextOP <= andx; --set signals for andx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0100" => 
                        NextOP <= notx; --set signals for notx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0011" => 
                        NextOP <= srlx; --set signals for srlx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0010" => 
                        NextOP <= sllx; --set signals for sllx
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1';
                         mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0001" => 
                        NextOP <= ld;   --set signals for ld
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '0'; 
                        mem_rd <= '0'; 
                        mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '1'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0)&'0'; 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when "0000" => 
                        NextOP <= st;   --set signals for st
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '0'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1'; 
                        mem_wr <= '0';
                        R_we <= '0'; 
                        ctl_wd <= currIR(14 downto 0) & '0';
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                    when others =>
                        NextOP <= nop; --set signals for nop
                        NextPC <= CurrPC; 
                        NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                        NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                        nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                        nextDisp <= currDisp;
                        PCaEN <= '0'; 
                        SPEN <= '0'; 
                        PCdEN <= '0';
                        mem_cs <= '1'; 
                        mem_rd <= '1';
                         mem_wr <= '1';
                        R_we <= '0'; 
                        ctl_wd <= (others => '0'); 
                        const_out <= x"0000";
                end case;
            end if;

            NextState <= Execute;

        when Execute => -------------------------EXECUTE-------------------------
            case CurrOp is
                when call => --call
                    NextPC <= std_logic_vector( unsigned (CurrPC) + 1); 
                    NextSP <= CurrSP; 
                    NextIR <= CurrIR; 
                    nextStatus <= currStatus; 
                    nextDisp <= currDisp;
                    PCaEN <= '0'; 
                    SPEN <= '1'; 
                    PCdEN <= '1';   -- store CurrPC to M[SP]
                    mem_cs <= '0'; 
                    mem_rd <= '1'; 
                    mem_wr <= '0';
                    R_we <= '0'; 
                    ctl_wd <= (others => '0'); 
                    const_out <= x"0000";
            --for bn and bz, execution of operation is dependent on signals N and Z
                when others => null;
            end case;
            NextState <= WB;

        when WB =>      -------------------------WB-------------------------
            NextPC <= '0' & currIR(6 downto 0); 
            NextSP <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(CurrSP) - 1); 
            NextIR <= CurrIR; 
            NextOp <= CurrOp;
            PCaEN <= '0'; 
            SPEN <= '0'; 
            PCdEN <= '0';      -- setup fetch
            mem_cs <= '1'; 
            mem_rd <= '1'; 
            mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low; setup fetch
            R_we <= '0'; 
            ctl_wd <=  (others => '0'); -- "0000"; 
            const_out <= x"0000";
            NextState <= Fetch;

        -- when others =>  -------------------------OTHERS-------------------------
        --     -- Should never be in this state!
        --     NextPC <= x"00"; NextSP <= x"00"; NextIR <= x"00"; NextOp <= call;
        --     PCaEN <= '0'; SPEN <= '0'; PCdEN <= '0';      
        --     mem_cs <= '1'; mem_rd <= '1'; mem_wr <= '1';  -- active low
        --     R_we <= '0'; ctl_wd <= "00"; const_out <= x"FF";    
        --     NextState <= Reset;
    end case;
end process;

-- Sequential Logic (asynchronous reset; registers update at positive-edge clock)  
Regs : process(clk,rst)
Begin
    if rst = '0' then CurrState <= Reset;  -- Active Low Reset
        CurrOp <= sethi; 
        CurrPC <= x"0080"; 
        CurrSP <= x"FFFE"; 
        CurrIR <= (others=>'0');
        CurrStatus <= "00";
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then CurrState <= NextState; 
        CurrOp <= NextOp; 
        CurrPC <= NextPC; 
        CurrSP <= NextSP; 
        CurrIR <= NextIR; 
        CurrStatus <= NextStatus;
    end if;
end process Regs;
end behavior;
```

Comment: David, You actually brought up an issue with my logic that I hadn't noticed. CurrOP is a signal used to store the current operation for which I am building a control word. CurrIR is a 16 bit signal that stores the instruction word in my design and is what I _meant_ to be slicing. Unfortunately, even after fixing this logic error where I am no longer trying to improperly slice CurrOP, I still receive the same syntax error.

Comment: I found a couple of dozen small errors, but that one is caused by an `else if` instead of an `elsif`.

Comment: To avoid looking like I ignored your help, I wanted to thank you for spotting that erroneous space in the else if. I don't know how I didn't spot that, but it solved 90% of the issues I was having, and I've since fixed the rest.

Comment: @OmarianVolcae so the issue is resolved? upvote user1155120's answer and mark his answer as accepted then ;)

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius The OP's account has been inactive for more than 3 years.

Comment: @user1155120 hmpf, yeah... stackoverflow has offered me a great source of information. So, to do something back for the community, I had the intentions to tie up loose threads, e.g. clean the unanswered question list... But in the mean time I have given up this mission: I either get no response or the I get accused of stealing someones rep... It seems the community likes their threads loose. :-/

Comment: The community values questions and answers by upvoting based on values reflected in guidelines. The place to debate that would be [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). With the OP unavailable [this sand can't be changed to a pearl](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).  The unanswered question list is supposed to take care of itself. Question ranking affects finding them by search. Leave them untouched and they'll be removed sooner than later. There's already a system in place to deal with them.